# Hyperparameter tuning in Lasso without cross validation

Tags: cross-validation, optimization, lasso, hyperparameter

I am facing a Lasso-type optimization problem with some tuning parameters for the L1 penalty term. I am wondering if there is any method (apart from cross-validation) to determine the values of those hyperparameters **directly**. A rough estimate from the data or even a rule of thumb will be more than enough for me.

The reasons are that: (1) in my case it is too computationally expensive to do cross-validation and (2) sometimes my problem is not a fully supervised one, there might not be true labels involved (similar to clustering with sparsity)